# Problems with downloading a PDF file to local PC

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdfsharp

I am trying to download a PDF file created with PDFsharp from the webserver and to the local PC's downloadfolder. I have googled a lot and tried a lot with no success. I can create the PDF file correctly and save it to the disk - but I can not transfer/Download it to the local PC's downloadfolder.

I have tried the following code:

```
string filename = Server.MapPath("~\\Files\\Temp\\file.pdf");
document.Save(filename); //generate the physical file

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
document.Save(stream, false);
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
Response.Flush();
stream.Close();
Response.End();
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when the code runs? What isn't working?

Comment: @NateBarbettini Nothing happens - I can not see the file in the download folder :-(

Comment: @MichaelEriksen Have you tried adding logging to your code or used breakpoints to debug the program? If so, what were the results.

Comment: The first two lines make no sense. Why write to a local file when the `MemoryStream` is all you need? Maybe something's wrong in the code around the snippet shown here.

Comment: @IliassNassibane I have debugged the program with no success. I have followed it in Explorer - but nothing happens :-(

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow Yes you are right - I maybe not need to write to a local file, so I will delete this line and test my program again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `Content-Disposition`:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf"); 
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", binfile.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(binfile);
```

if you have update panel you have to set the button as postback trigger

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnID" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Not sure that's the missing bit. The official web sample does not have this line: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Clock-sample.ashx

Comment: @DragandDrop Correct link. Most likely this sample is the prototype for the code in the original post (except for the first two lines that make no sense).

Comment: I have tried to set the Content-Disposition - but I still can not download the file :-(